# media de los números de una secuencia

Tags: c++, c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas, en la opción 4 tengo un problema con la media del array.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se puede ver que recorro todo el array, y voy sumando los valores, pero al hacerlo, me sale la media de cada uno de los números introducidos y no del total.
Si alguien me puediera ayudar se lo agradecería mucho...

Comment: Limita el uso de etiquetas solamente a aquel lenguaje que estés empleando, además el código debe ir como texto, así la comunidad podrá ayudarte mejor, lee [ask]

Comment: **`C#`**, **`C++`** y **`C`** son distintos.

Comment: Puedo suponer que estás usando C por el uso de `printf`, pero también tiene  diferencias con C++. Por ejemplo, en C no existen las clases.

Comment: Tienes a media y el printf que está abajo, ambas instrucciones debes dejarla fuera del for (abajo)

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del ciclo sólo debes acumular; una vez terminada la secuencia puedes calcular la media:

```
suma = 0.00;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    suma += secuencia[i];
}

media = suma / N;
printf("La media de la secuencia es %.2f\n", media);
```